# Route me (Alpstein fork) for iOS markers wiggle in higher zoom levels

Tags: ios, markers, route-me

I am trying to get Route me working with building maps and I have a little problem.

Try one of the examples of route me with markers. When you zoom in as max as you can, markers starts wiggle and doesn't stick to map. It doesn't look nice and it is level 19, in buildings I use level 21 and the marker is just flying around.

I am just guessing, but it seems like there is some grid system where the spacing are to big and the marker is trying to clip to it.

Do you have any experience with that?

EDIT:
I found that the problem is in RMMapScrollView. Somehow it doesn't catch every pixel when the user is interacting with scrollview. But only when zoom is bigger than 16 or something like that ... really weird.

I don't know how to fix it, I will switch to original route-me that doesn't have this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you post your xcode project?

Comment: Hello Andrew, here is the git repository https://github.com/tkohout/RouteMe-TestMarkers . It's just altered version of Layered Map with my map source and one marker.